# Confidence margin for logical verification

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-logic, wittgenstein, bertrand-russell, logical-positivism

I'm starting to read Wittgenstein and I keep circling around a problem, which I'll lay out with the following ideas:

a. Logical space is the totality of external reality.

b. A proposition is logical so long as it verifiable, e.g. maps onto logical space.

c. Regardless of the precision of instrumentation used to observe reality, perception will always cause some degree of distortion of external reality.

If a, b, and c are accepted, then how can any proposition be determined as logical?

Is there some kind of confidence margin that people use (consciously or not) to verify claims?

Comment: "logical space" is an undefined concept in the [Tractatus](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/wittgenstein/#TracLogiPhil): **1.13** The facts in logical space are the world. We may say that " logical space" is the collection of all "possibilities" and that the world (the actual one) is the sub-collection of the logical space made of "actualized" possibilities: the *facts*.

Comment: Ohh, I think I had a misunderstanding on what logical space was, thank you. Could I then think of logical space as a quantum field and the world as the quantum field observed at a point in time?

Comment: A *proposition* is a linguistic entity: it is made of *signs*. As such, also a proposition is a fact of the world (see **3.143**). What do you mean with "A proposition is logical so long as it verifiable..."?

Comment: IMO, the *Tractatus* is not about "perception", nor about "confidence margin" regarding eveidence supporting claims.

Comment: 5.4733 "Frege says: Every legitimately constructed proposition must have a sense."

Comment: Sense is something that demands verification, no? Otherwise it is nonsense.

Comment: How could perception not be central to this?

Comment: Sense for Frege is one of the two "components" of meaning; it is the thought expressed by the proposition. For W, the sense of a proposition is similar: **2.221** What a picture represents is its sense.

Comment: So then if I think of a pig flying over the Eiffel Tower wearing a Lebron James basketball jersey and I want to communicate this image to you, and then I say "think of a pig flying over the Eiffel Tower wearing a Lebron James basketball jersey", then the proposition is legitimately constructed. Am I correct to then say this proposition has sense?

Comment: The most famous Wittgenstein saying is: "The limits of my language mean the limits of my world.”, moreover, he claims that a sentence (a proposition, if you will) has meaning only as a result of the "rule" of the "game" being played (his "language game" concept). So, according to him, your flying pig with jersey sentence makes sense to those, who understand it in english language. And I think there's plenty of those people, so, approximately, you're correct :)

Comment: @k-wasilewski except there are many ideas that are non-linguistic.  Are the limits of a rabbit's language the limits of its world?  Of course not, for it has no language.  But it does have a brain similar to ours, with vision, smell, emotion, and so forth - reactive and non-linguistic but surely part of its world.

Comment: Your statement about propositions is wrong. Propositions are not sentences or linguistic entities. They are ideas that are expressed in some kind of language. The meaning of the ideas in that language can be literally verifiable not the proposition.  Russell is speaking on Mathematical logic as opposed to the Philosophy side.

Comment: @causative I've often wondered the same thing. I hesitate to disagree with Wittgenstein (and assume my own ignorance). In this regard, what do you think about symbolism as a way of engaging with the world that does not fully rely upon linguistic faculties?

Comment: @Logikal I think I understand. Are you suggesting that my understanding of a proposition was focusing on the symbol (word) and not the thing in which it signifies? For example, Σ, sigma, sum of all, somme de tout all point to the same thing. The thing being pointed to is the proposition.  Is that correct?

Comment: A proposition can't be pointed to, seen or heard. A proposition is a concept. In a language that expresses the concept we can make a judgment such as true or false about the idea or concept. For example there would be no need to quote someone expressing a proposition. You can Express the same concept using a different set of words or sentences in English. Do you as an adult need to use the word "STUPID" literally to Express that concept? The answer is NO. You know people in the workplace or school do it all the time without being direct like that

Comment: @Logikal ah this is getting at my original question. How is the true/false judgement made? What are the conditions that must be satisfied for truth or falsehood?

Comment: There are distinct types of truth. One is contingent truths: temporary truths like weather conditions which are not true forever. Ot is not forever raining or snowing some where on Earth. Objective truths are forever true. These are not temporary: a woman will always be a human being or it is not a woman  Beliefs or opinions are not counted. Don't confuse truth with law or people in authority. Those can be seen by other people as truth. The same goes with the media. That doesn't mean truth either but some people see it as truth. You need context to discuss truth or it gets confusing .

Comment: @Logikal I totally agree with you and disagree with Wittgenstein, just wanted to throw in a pebble to the conversation regarding W...

Comment: @causative ---||---

Comment: If you want to learn logic, you need to find the right trees, not get stuck in the weeds.